# .cs file changes not reflected by IIS 6.0

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I have configured my web using iis 6.0. It worked fine first time. I then made a change in aspx.cs file(using notepad assuming that .net on iis supports dynamic compilation) to hide the banner and reloaded the site and noticed that the change didn't get picked up. I have read several similar posting and tried their suggestions (e.g. change web config file, restart iis, restart app recycle pool, delete files and reload files, disable cache, clear browser cookies/cache, delete asp.net temp. files etc) but have not been able to resolve the issue. what am I missing? I am using ASP.NET 4.0 integrated pipeline. When I tried with classic pipeline .net compilation option, it complains about CGI and does not load the page.

Comment: Maybe your project isn't meant to be dynamically compiled?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using the `CodeFile` directive at the top of the `.aspx` page instead of `CodeBehind`.  This tells .NET to compile the `.cs` file dynamically when it's needed.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="MyPage.aspx.cs" %>
```